# Why didn't Maleficent grow her wings back?

Tags: plot-explanation, maleficent

We saw that Maleficent can turn a bird into human/dragon etc. She is so powerful that she can grow tree wall within seconds. She can curse a girl so strongly that she even can't break her own curse. So powerful!! Okay, so why can't she just grow new wings? OR when Stefan took them, why she didn't try to find the wings? At least she could try to know what Stefan did with the wings....

Is there any reason for this that I missed?

Comment: I don't think it is explicitly addressed in the movie. My best guess is that she can apply transformations to other objects/beings, but not to herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Did she know that where her wings are?**

Definitely not. When her wings got removed, she wasn't aware of it because of the liquid she drank. She found out next morning. After much time has passed, she never mentioned that she knew where her wings were. She doesn't have far-sight or a fortune ball to know where is her wings are, or whether they are still unaffected.

**Why doesn't she grow her wings?**

Because she can't. She made Diaval as a shape-shifter and called him her wings. She needs her wings, but she can't grow them back. That's why she made Diaval as a raven shape-shifter.

**Why didn't she try to get back her wings?**

Through her actions, it's clear that she wants only revenge. She hasn't given a thought to getting back her wings and she might not even know if they are still there. And direct fight with Stefan is risky because he knows her weakness.

**But she can do that....she can do that but why not bring back her wings?**

Limitation!

Comment: haha. fair enough. Yeah I wish there was some attempt to know about those wings. Movie makers could have shown that Maleficent tried to know, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

We can argue all day long whether she should have had the power to grow her wings back, but I have another take on this:

Stefan represented trust and love in your enemy. There is a line where the narrator says something along the line: she doesn't understand the envy and power lust of men that made Stefan spend less time with her. So even seeing and being aware of all this in Stefan himself she still loved and trusted him.

When he betrayed her he betrayed all that love and trust. She didn't want to grow/take her wings back because she needed a constant reminder of the betrayer of men, a constant reminder of why she is suffering and why she has to be evil. When she is turned back to being good by Aurora she can finally accept her wings back.

Loosing her wings and gaining them back symbolize loosing all the good in her and then gaining it back.